# Sauce service doesn't work with mobile tests

Tags: npm, webdriver-io, saucelabs, wdio-v6

I am using `sauce-service` package to send names of tests (feature files) and see them on `Sauce Labs`, everything is working fine when I am using web tests but unfortunately when I try to set mobile config it doesn't seem to work. What I am missing?

My mobile config:

```
exports.config = {
    ...config,
    ...{
        user: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
        key: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
        testobject_api_key: process.env.SAUCE_RDC_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: 'eu',
        specs: [
            './features/*'
        ],
        maxInstances: 1,
        capabilities: [{
            deviceName: 'Samsung Galaxy S',
            automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
            platformName: 'Android',
            idleTimeout: 180,
            cacheId: new Date().getTime(),
            noReset: true,
            autoGrantPermissions: true,
            orientation: 'PORTRAIT',
            newCommandTimeout: 180,
            build: 'test',
          //name: 'test', <- Hardcoded test name, it should be name from feature file
            maxInstances: 1,
        }],
        services: ['sauce'],
    }
}
```

My package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.1",
    "@rpii/wdio-html-reporter": "^6.3.1",
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^7.5.7",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^6.3.6",
    "@wdio/cli": "^6.9.1",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^6.8.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.9.1",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^6.8.0",
    "@wdio/sauce-service": "^6.10.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.8.1",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-source-map-support": "^2.1.3",
    "chromedriver": "^91.0.1",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^6.0.4",
    "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "^2.0.2",
    "wdio-json-reporter": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

Is a problem with a package, `sauce labs`, `webdriverio`, or something else?

I will appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with WebdriverIO V6, you need to upgrade to at least version 7, and at least version [7.7.4](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/releases/tag/v7.7.4) of the Sauce Service so it will work.